# Windows 7 command line jps not working

Tags: java, windows-7

Others have asked this question but the answer is usually the same and not helpful to my problem. I installed JDK, and added `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin` to the path system variable. I checked, jps.exe is in that directory. I restarted my computer but still have had no luck. When I run `jps` I get the error:

```
'jps is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable command or batch file'
```

When I run `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\jps.exe` on the command line it works fine. Working in Windows 7.

Comment: Can you provide us with your current full path value? Are you sure 1.7.0.25 is the correct version and that `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin` is a valid directory? By the way, you shouldn't need to restart your computer to see the changes you've made to the path.

Comment: The directory and version are fine, I can run 'jps' if my working directory is 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin'

Answer (score 1):

Mildly obvious mistake, but I realize that I had spaces in between the directories in my path and that caused them to not be recognized. So I had `%OTHER_PATH%; C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25; %ANOTHER_PATH%`, which I just had to switch to `%OTHER_PATH%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25;%ANOTHER_PATH%`

Answer (score 0):

Your JDK bin directory does not exist in PATH variable.
To add this you need to do below steps.

1. Go to "Control Panel >> System >> Advanced system settings >>
   Environment Variables
2. Click 'Path' from System variables
3. Click Edit.
4. Now add the path "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_72\bin"
   Now open command window and write jps. It will work now.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above solutions, still if you have issue with jps command,  Please check whether the default system installed java(JRE) path is already available in the Path variable.

My case i faced the same issue and observed the following path already available in the path variable.

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath"

So I had to change the position(move up) of my new JAVA_HOME path, new JAVA_HOME path is above the default oracle javapath.